# JSF Lifecycle with immediate=true

Tags: jsf, page-lifecycle

When I read article **[Listen and debug JSF lifecycle phases](http://balusc.blogspot.tw/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)**
wrtten by @BalusC, I have some trouble understanding the article.

While **[Add immediate="true" to UIInput and UICommand](http://balusc.blogspot.tw/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#AddImmediateTrueToUIInputAndUICommand)**, It says:

> **Note for all components with immediate:** as the Update model values phase is skipped, the value bindings aren't been set and the value binding getters will return null. But the values are still available...
>
> **Note for other components without immediate:** any other UIInput components inside the same form which don't have immediate="true" set will not be converted, validated nor updated, but behind the scenes the inputComponent.setSubmittedValue(submittedValue) will be executed before the action() method will be executed. You can retrieve...

Is that means no matter with or without `immediate`, the **`Update model values phase`** will always skipped because the `immediate="true"` in the h:commandButton? If so, the value in backing bean will not change, right?

However, in the [last paragraph](http://balusc.blogspot.tw/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#WhenShouldIUseTheImmediateAttribute) of the article, it summarized **"when to use immediate=true"** and mentioned:

> - If set in both UIInput and UICommand components, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the UIInput component(s) which does not have this attribute set. Use this to skip the processing of the entire form except for certain fields (with immediate). E.g. "Password forgotten" button in a login form with a required and immediate username field and a required but non-immediate password field.

I am confused because I thought  **`Process validations Phase`** and **`Update model values Phase`** are skipped no matter there are/aren't `immediate` once you set `immdediate=true` in `h:commandButton` in the same form.

I must misunderstood something, please help me clarify it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part indeed needs clarification.

What is meant in the summary, is **the job** which is normally executed in the mentioned phases (i.e. applying request values, processing validations and updating model values), even though they happen in the apply request values phase.

I have updated the article accordingly.

Comment: Still don't get it...
When I  Add immediate="true" to UIInput and UICommand, is the mentioned phases skipped for all components with/without immediate?

Comment: So when I set immediate=true for "Password forgotten", the processing (job) happened in the "Apply request values Phase", and the following phases are skipped. So I can take advantage of this to process only commandButton but not other component without immediate!

Comment: And if I set required and immediate username field and a required but non-immediate password field, the username field will be converted and validated while not bound to value in bean; and the password field will not be converted and validated at all.